# Multiple Dropdown Filtering

Tags: javascript, filter, dropdown

I very quite new to Javascript, so I'll detail the steps below to re-create the problem. I've also set up a jsfiddle

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kmq34ddx/)

Steps to recreate the problem:

1. Select 'Work Queues' from dropdown 1.
2. Select 'Google' from dropdown 2. (Google is shown - works ok).
3. Select 'Yahoo' from dropdown 2. (Yahoo is shown - works ok).
4. Select 'Agents' from dropdown 1, then 'Claire' from dropdown 2 (Claire is shown - works ok).
5. Select 'Darren' from dropdown 2 (Darren is shown - works ok).
6. Select 'Work Queues' again, from dropdown 1...Darren continues to show...this is the problem)

Why does Darren continue to show even when a different option is selected? What code can be placed to help resolve this?

Many Thanks

HTML:

> 1.
>
> ```
>           <td>
>             <div>
>               <select style="width: 100%; border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; font-family: Sky Text Regular; font-size: 18px; padding:
> ```
>
> 5px;" height="200px">
>                       Select Category...
>                       Work Queues
>                       Agents
>
> ```
>           <td>
>             <div class="queuelist agentlist largetext">2. </div>
>           </td>
>
>           <td>
>             <center>
>               <div class="catlist" style="font-family: Sky Text Regular; font-size: 28px; color: #009CDD;"></div>
>             </center>
>
>             <div class="queuelist">
>               <select style="width: 90%; border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; font-family: Sky Text Regular; font-size: 18px; padding:
> ```
>
> 5px;" height="200px">
>                       Select Queue...
>                       Google
>                       Yahoo
>
> ```
>             <div class="agentlist">
>               <select style="width: 90%; border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; font-family: Sky Text Regular; font-size: 18px; padding:
> ```
>
> 5px;" height="200px">
>                       Select Agent...
>                       Claire
>                       Darren
>
> ```
>               </select>
>             </div>
>
>           </td>
>           </div>
>
>         </tr>   </table> </center>
> ```
>
> Google
>       Yahoo
>
> ```
> <div class="claire agentcard">Claire</div>
> <div class="darren agentcard">Darren</div> </center> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you were triggering the function on the correct select menu, you were running through every single select menu's selected option element, the subsequent selects erasing the effect of the one you wanted.

Replace this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
```

with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).children("option:selected").each(function() {
```

To show a newly shown select's already selected option:
add a change trigger for the second select:

```
  if ($(this).attr("value") == "queuelist") {
   ....
  $(".queuelist").show();
    $(".queuelistselect").change();
```

(same for "agentlist").

[Working Fiddle - Edited](https://jsfiddle.net/wp9ke0td/)

Comment: 99.9%. So if i were following the steps above, and instead of step 6 failing, it works with your solution...it doesnt display the previously opened Work Queue, in this case Yahoo...

Comment: Edited it yet again because I had messed up the menu names. This is a minimal change to your code style. Ideally, you could've done some nesting.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you so much!

Comment: Random question, is it possible to have the target page completely refreshed when an option is selected in the dropdown? I would find this especially useful as the contents on the target page can change and it would be good for the user to always get the default page

Comment: It is possible, if you mean a page reload, via of course window.location.assign(url) on some select's change event...but that would mean previous selections would also be reset. Or, a form submit must be triggered on the same event, using javascript (.submit() ).

Comment: So for example, imagine if I selected Item 1 in dropdown 1, and then item 1 in dropdown 2 - results are shown via iframe. On this iframe there is a link. I click this link and the contents of the frame change as expected. Now if the user then selects another item in the dropdown (any item) but then reverts back to the original item where the link was clicked, rather than the original contents of dropdown 1, item 1 being displayed, the contents of the link were still being shown. does that make sense? I'd like the original contents of dropdown 1, item 1 to show again.